# Picasso in list adapter is not loading images from cache

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using picasso to load images from server in my list adapter. When I'm scrolling list up and down Picasso keeps allocate more and more memory, screen below:
[image]

Here is part of my list adapter:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
            //init list item
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subfood_item, viewGroup,
                    false);

            viewHolder.mImgvPicture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgvPicture);
            viewHolder.mTvHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
            viewHolder.mTvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            //list item is used again - get all references for view
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Product product = mItems.get(position);

        viewHolder.mTvHeader.setText(product.getName());
        viewHolder.mTvDescription.setText(product.getDescription());


        if (product.isAsset()) {
            String folderPath = "file:///android_asset/product/";
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(folderPath + product.getPath()).fit().centerCrop().
                    into(viewHolder.mImgvPicture);
        } else {
            RestUtils.loadImageWithPicasso(RestUtils.URL_IMAGE_FROM_PRODUCT + product.getNetId(), viewHolder.mImgvPicture);
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

First part - loading from assets is fine. Problem is with:

```
RestUtils.loadImageWithPicasso(RestUtils.URL_IMAGE_FROM_PRODUCT + product.getNetId(), viewHolder.mImgvPicture);
```

I've wrapped this with additional method because of server authentication and offline caching. Below is code of RestUtils.loadImageWithPicasso

```
 public static void loadImageWithPicasso(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        float dp = App.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        if(dp<=4.0f){
            url = url+"?size="+(int)Math.floor(dp);
        }  else {
            url = url+"?size=4";
        }

        String requestUrl = RestUtils.getUrl(url);

        OkHttpClient picassoClient = new OkHttpClient();

        final String finalUrl = url;
        String hash = RestUtils.getHashed(finalUrl);
        Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(RestUtils.HEADER, RestUtils.getHashed(finalUrl))
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        };

        picassoClient.interceptors().add(interceptor);

        File httpCacheDir = new File(App.getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), RestUtils.IMAGE_CACHE);
        long httpCacheSize = 40 * 1024 * 1024;
        Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
        picassoClient.setCache(cache);

        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(App.getContext()).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(picassoClient)).build();

        picasso.load(requestUrl)
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

Even if I quit from fragment, memory is still allocated.

Comment: Could it be that your server is returning the image with status code 200 and not 304 Not modified?

Comment: Here are server response https://imgur.com/RQPn34T

Comment: @axierjhtjz so it should return 304?

Comment: It should if the image is sending the right headers, look at Http cache to understand 304 status code, If-Modified-Since and Etags.

Comment: I was thinking that this is because of OkHttpClient, so I've tried regular use of picasso with random cat image:
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(App.getContext()).build();

        picasso.load("http://blog.karmako.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/tapetki_koty_0721.jpg")
                .into(viewHolder.mImgvPicture);
But result is the same.

Comment: Under the hood Picasso uses OkHttp

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you can blame picasso on this one.  You are building a custom `Picasso` instance with a new cache on every image load. Every time you call `loadImageWithPicasso`, your code is allocating at least the following new objects -`OkHttpClient`, `Interceptor`, `File`, `Cache`, `Picasso` and at least two `String`'s.  You should only be building your `Picasso` instance once.

There are a couple ways you choose to do that.  One is -

Divide `loadImageWithPicasso` into two methods `createCustomPicasso` that returns your custom picasso object, call that *once* in your UI code and save in a member variable.

Then, modify `loadImageWithPicasso` so that it takes a picasso instance you can pass in --

```
public static void loadImageWithPicasso(Picasso picasso, String url, ImageView imageView)
```

and then have it do the url-specific modifications before issuing the requests.

As a last note, your `Interceptor` should be getting the data it needs to modify the request out of `chain.getRequest()` instead of using data from outside its immediate scope.  You are referencing `finalUrl` inside your interceptor.  It like can be replaced with `chain.getRequest().urlString()` See the documentation on [interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) for a good walk through on the usage.